# junit test - Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Boolean

Tags: java, junit

I have the following test -

```
public void testStore() throws ItemNotStoredException {
    Boolean result = itemSrvc.storeItem(items);
    Assert.assertFalse(result);
        }
```

but I get the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Boolean.

What it is testing...

```
public void storeItem(Items items) throws ItemNotStoredException {
    try { 
        ObjectOutputStream output = new
                ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("itemdatabase"));

        output.writeObject(items);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ItemNotStoredException ("Unable to store file", e);
    }


}
```

To clarify - I dont want storeItem to return anything, I am just trying to test it, so perhaps my test itself is just wrong.  If that is the case, any advise on how to fix the test would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `storeItem` doesn't return a value, so you can't store/compare/anything it.

Comment: Obviously `storeItem()` does not return `boolean` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the case when the save fails, and assuming that an exception should get thrown if the save fails, then you could change the test to look like this:

```
@Test(expected= ItemNotStoredException.class) 
public void testStore() throws ItemNotStoredException {
    itemSrvc.storeItem(items);
}
```

or if you're using an ancient version of JUnit:

```
public void testStore() throws Exception {
    try {
        itemSrvc.storeItem(items);
        Assert.fail();
    }
    catch (ItemNotStoredException e) {
    }
 }
```

Comment: That tests the save mechanics, but not whether or not it actually worked--you'd need to read it back in, particularly if there's any custom serialization. This just integration-tests the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

`storeItem()` has a `void` return type, but the code is attempting to assign it to `Boolean`: which is illegal.

A possible restructuring of the test (assuming no exception expected):

```
public void testStore()
{
    try
    {
        itemSrvc.storeItem(items);
    }
    catch (ItemNotStoredException e)
    {
        Assert.fail("storeItem() failure: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the return type of `storeItem()` is `void`, which is what you are trying to capture as the `Boolean result`.

Answer (score 2):

storeItem doesnt return anything but you are assigning a boolean as the result of that function.

You need to return a boolean from your storeItem method.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are making a method call to a method that returns void (nothing) but are attempting to store this result in a Boolean!

Answer (score 1):

Answering the underlying question:

You'd have to read the file.

Or, better, inject the output stream so you can define it in your test, then read the object stream directly.